# Boost score based on the array length in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation

I have an array of strings like this.

```
{
  array: ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

this is an example on how I boost the score based on the name:

```
text: {
      query: filters?.name,
      path: "name",
      score: { boost: { value: 10 } },
      fuzzy: {
        maxEdits: 2,
        prefixLength: 4,
      },
    },
```

**But how can I boost the score based on the length of a given array?**

For example if the array has length 3, I boost the score by 3 points.

How can I do that in an aggregation?

Comment: You can use $size operator in mongdb

Comment: i know, but i can i boost the score with $size?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by boost the score, can you show your whole input document and the expected output document

Comment: i want to boost the score in the exact same way i did in the example.

Comment: score: { boost: { value: {$size:"$array"} } } expected to do the job ...

Comment: the query now returns this error: "compound.score.boost.value" must be a number

Comment: Please add the whole aggregation query that you are trying, it will be easy to debug